# Grails or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grails, groovy

I know that there have been plenty of topics describing this topic but I still can't put up my mind what to choose.First of all, I need you to know that I am a student in his last year, who will probably continue studying for a few years. However, I'm trying to find what I would benefit most from.

I've been in contact with RoR last year; seeing Ruby's squirky syntax amazed me, and Rails CoC and DRY principles make me dream. I've written some scripts to generate sql statements in Ruby, but that is about all.

I'm considered to be a  java developer, as they call me the java guy on school, (no, i do not consider myself good, on the contrary, every day I realise more how much more i've got to learn). Now, I've taught myself several technologies related to java. To make my work easier, I opted learning hibernate and maven. Now we are developping an application in Spring + Spring MVC.

Grails caught my attention lately since it is built on top of these technologies, and uses a language that is similar to java, and allows access to java classes.

However, i'm not sure what is the best way to go. Should I struggle through Ruby's quirkyness first, and learn Rails? Or would learning Grails first give me an advantage over learning RoR?

Also, as far as from what i've read, RoR would give me a bigger advantage on the market than grails would; but how do I get a "proof" that I can use RoR? Would it be enough to be able to show applications made using RoR?

Comment: I would ask this on programmers.stackexchange.com as may not have a correct answer.

Comment: well, of course programmers seems like a better place, but it didn't even have a tag yet for "grails" and only 11 for "groovy". I've put it on there as well, in case someone happens to read it there, though there is more hope on an answer here.

Comment: You should check out JRuby when you get a chance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've mentioned that you're already into Java, Spring and Hibernate. Well, Grails is based on those - in **continuation**.

Spring is a very comprehensive, powerful, and modular, framework. Hibernate has been a de-facto standard, and is compliant with Java EE 6's JPA. Both are most **relevant** in the Java world.

So, there's the aspect of **consistency** of your technical knowledge. From Spring/Hibernate to Grails/GORM you'll have **cohesive** knowledge.

Another central aspect is your **options**. When dealing with Spring, you'll probably soon learn how easy it is to change complete architectural layers, like, changing the view technology, or database layer, or simply exporting a web service by configuration. Spring-based applications can be highly **modular**, and you can **plug-in** almost any technology scope you could think of. - So you have many ways to go further if desired.

The Spring framework has been written from the ground to foster **best practices**. Just dealing with that framework will teach you a lot.

---

Admittedly, I haven't dealt with Ruby on Rails, at all. I regard it a rather isolated technology, while Grails is a (Java and Spring) **integration framework** to me, with the backends/grounds and options as mentioned above.

---

When evaluating **practical aspects** of technologies, it's always a good idea to do some **research** on [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) and [Indeed job trends](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends). Other **indicators** on popularity/relevance are the numbers (and trends) of mailing list messages for [Grails](http://grails.markmail.org/) vs. [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.markmail.org/), and (not quite an accurate measurement for niche languages) the [TIOBE programming languages index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).

---

Finally, **Java** had experienced several years of starvation and uncertainty in the past (despite of being one of the few all-time languages and frameworks, at all, and a **long-burner**). Recently, however, several evident signs came up that appear to seriously forecast a much brighter future than before.

Comment: If you see a bright future for Java because Oracle bought Sun, you might check the history on Oracle's acquired tech: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acquisitions_by_Oracle

Comment: However, I upvoted you, your analysis on how Grails is a continuation of his knowledge makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks Fábio. - I'm well recognizing that this is the first time for Oracle to not just buy a company but to buy in into a larger ecosystem. - That's certainly a very new challenge to Oracle, and they're on their learning track; however, most of their decisions are most welcomed by most of the Java community. - There's a need for lots of discussions, and even opposition/contradiction, but I do "smell" honesty and willingness at the sides of Oracle. And new forms of communication, which Oracle never needed to use before. (I'm listening to Java/Oracle news and discussions at a daily basis.)

Answer (score 7):

I've used both frameworks pretty extensively, and both have their warts and advantages, but when you come right down to it, there aren't that many differences for someone coming from your background.

In my area (Minneapolis), the grails market is larger than the rails market, but that isn't the case everywhere.

I'd pick whichever one has the user group in your area that you connect with the most.  That will be your best bet for finding work with whichever one you choose.

Comment: Grails is more than "Grails": You can leverage the underlying Spring framework, and "plug-in" technologies of any scope, including the database (Hibernate, JPA, myBatis, JDBC), service (web services, JMS, RMI, Hessian, JSON, Quartz), and view layer (JSF, GWT, ZKOSS, PDF, Excel, Flash). - Being Spring-based, Grails is modular, and there's a wealth of Java libraries and frameworks available.

Answer (score 4):

As a Grails developer...

1. Grails runs on mature and proven virtual machine (JVM) and really do the best performance compared to any dynamic language, even static Java/JSP when using Freemarker Plugin! http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/
2. Grails uses Groovy, so it has an **almost flat learning curve for Java developers**. You can write Java syntax and gradually learning Groovy syntax, closures, meta-programming and more... getting expressiveness and agility of a dynamic language like Ruby.
3. Grails **uses modern principles and practices** like Convention over Configuration and Scaffolding, just like Rails taught us all.
4. Grails uses a mature platform, so it **comes w/ all great existing java libs**, mature groups and projects like Apache, Eclipse, JBoss and so on for reporting, file exporting, legacy integration... and many new well-supported libs and frameworks from Google and others like Guice, Guava, Collections and so on...
5. Grails uses a vastly used platform, so **you can reuse all your existing java libs**. You could reuse your entities, utilities, and so on...
6. Grails use existing Java infrastructure, so it comes with **many ready & mature server w/ great documentation** (i.e install, configuration) Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, and so on...
7. Grails use existing Java infrastructure, so it **scales very well w/ many ready & mature options**: Server Clustering, Open Terracotta, Second Level Cache, and so on...
8. Grails runs on top of well-know and vastly documented frameworks like Hibernate, Spring MVC, Hibernate, SiteMesh, and so on... and **you can step down into abstraction when you need**, i.e batch imports, complex reporting queries, complex interfaces, and so on..
9. Grails has a **great plugin ecossystem** much like Ruby Gems and **can use all existing Maven-based lib repositories** to resolve dependencies.
10. Grails uses a solid platform, so **you'll always reuse your libs (JARs) with the next Language of The Year (LOTY)**. "Write Once, Run Ever"

Hope that helps! :-)

Comment: That benchmark site seems to be broken. There are no results.

Comment: Also, if you run Rails on JRuby then almost every statement you made works for Rails too.

Comment: @rwilliams Check this real 2011 use case comparing Grails with Rails and many other Java frameworks: http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/. Now we are in 2012, and Grails 2.0 is here and is even more fast! No to mention that Groovy 2.0 is out and the next Grails will fly. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you liked Ruby's syntax and simplicity, go with Rails, and run it on top of [JRuby](http://jruby.org/), which will give you access to Java classes as well.

Check: http://blogs.oracle.com/coolstuff/entry/using_java_classes_in_jruby

Comment: But, will this help with changing the database layer to, i.e., JPA, changing parts of the service layer to web services by mere configuration, or changing the view layer to, i.e., JSF or ZKOSS? - Using JRuby, you have access to Java *libraries* but cannot integrate Java *frameworks*.

Comment: That's correct, using JRuby you'll be using the stock Rails framework, running on a Java implemented Ruby VM. JRuby will provide you access to Java libraries and JDBC drivers, but not much more. Some might thing of it as a good thing, like I do... IMO, Java frameworks are a little bloated, and sometimes you feel like you are using C4 to kill an ant. I love the Java environment and VM, but hate most of the Java frameworks.